# Chrome and Firefox equivalent of IE's window.opener.functionName()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am using window.opener.functionName() in IE to call the parent function from a child window, which is working perfectly fine. However, the same is not working in Chrome/Firefox.

I tried window.top.functionName(); parent.window.top.functionName() and numerous others. None are working.

Can anybody help!

**EDIT**
Here is the code.
Note that I have 2 level hierarchy. I need to call the updateHTML() function of Parent.jsp from ChildCall2.jsp file

Parent.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Parent function call test</TITLE>
<script>
    function openwindow(url)
    {
         Hints=window.open(url, 'Hints', "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=475,height=225");
         if(Hints.blur)
            Hints.focus();
    }

    function updateHTML()
    {
        alert("Parent called successfully");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onFocus="">
<a href="javascript:openwindow('ChildCall.jsp')"> Click Me </a>
</body> 
</html>
```

ChildCall.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Child function call test</TITLE>
<script>
    function openwindow(url)
    {
         Hints=window.open(url, 'Hints', "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=475,height=225");
         if(Hints.blur)
            Hints.focus();
    }

    function updateHTML1()
    {
        alert("Parent call function");
        window.opener.updateHTML();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onFocus="">
<a href="javascript:openwindow('ChildCall2.jsp')"> Click Me </a>
</body> 
</html>
```

ChildCall2.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Child function2 call test</TITLE>
<script>
    function openwindow(url)
    {
         Hints=window.open(url, 'Hints', "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=475,height=225");
         if(Hints.blur)
            Hints.focus();
    }

    function updateHTML2()
    {
        alert("Parent call function2");
        window.opener.updateHTML1();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onFocus="">
<a href="javascript:updateHTML2()"> Click Me to call parent function </a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console of the newly created window?

Comment: Nope. No error. Just that the function isn't getting called.

Comment: Refresh the window and peek the console again...

Comment: You are right.. Getting this error - `TypeError: window.opener.updateDocHTML is not a function`

Comment: On the main page `updateDocHTML` is not defined then. A timing issue? Something IE-only code stops the execution in Chrome and FF before or in `updateDocHTML`?

Comment: Yes. There is a timer in the window where I call this updateDocHTML function. The timer closes the window automatically after a few seconds. There is no issue in this functionality. It works fine. But, there is no IE specific code here.

Comment: Hii guys, can anyone update on this!!

Comment: Well, I created test pages for this, and they are working fine in IE, Chrome and FF. Without seeing your code there's not much to "update".

Comment: I have added the code. I have 2 level hierarchy. May be, that's where the problem lies.. Would you mind having a look into it.. Thanks

Comment: At a quick glance it looks like all your pop-ups have the same name (`window.open(url, 'Hints', ...)`), maybe this confuses other browsers? Also detecting if a window has `blur` method is unnecessary, just do `Hints.focus()`.

Comment: You are spot on.. I renamed the windows.. It is working fine. I am able to call the parent function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Can you please leave a reply in Answers, so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your pop-ups have the same name `(window.open(url, 'Hints', ...))`, this might confuse some browsers so they recognize some other window being their opener.

Just a sidenote, detecting if a window has `blur` method is unnecessary, just do `Hints.focus()`.